How To NOT Have to Double Click with the Fill Tool (Grease Pencil 3)
I was wondering if anyone knew how to make it so you don't have to double click every time to use the grease pencil fill tool.
In previous versions you could uncheck the "Visual Aids" option in the fill tool's advanced settings.

However in 4.3 (Grease Pencil 3) this does not fix it, and there seems to be no way to be able to fill an area with a single click. Anybody run into this issue?
Thank you.

Hello I noticed this problem too when I was experimenting here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/328320/why-cant-i-fill-shapes-with-slightly-larger-gaps-in-grease-pencil

This issue has already been reported on the official Blender community forum. You can find the discussion here: https://devtalk.blender.org/t/blender-4-3-grease-pencil-v3-feedback/32115/125

Hello and welcome. This is Q&A site run by volunteers, we are not programmers nor in any way associated with the Blender Foundation, decision making nor development process of the software. For bug reports please see Where to Report a Bug
