Why Can't I Fill Shapes with Slightly Larger Gaps in Grease Pencil?
I drew two shapes: one with a smaller gap and another with a slightly bigger gap. I can fill the shape with the smaller gap, but the shape with the larger gap refuses to fill.
I assume there’s a setting in Blender that allows you to adjust the threshold for gap closure to enable filling.

I found the Gap Closure setting under Advanced and experimented with different values, both smaller and larger, but none of them worked. How does this setting actually function, and why isn’t it allowing me to fill the shape with a slightly larger gap?

By the way, in Blender 4.3, unticking Visual Aids does not function like in Blender 4.2 where you supposedly can fill with single click. There's apparently no way to do single click fills anymore with 4.3
